# SSIS Race Condition

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis, ssis-2008

We utilize SSIS (SQL/BIDS 2008) to generate close to 1000 reports per day.  The same package is scheduled 5 times in SQL Agent, on staggered schedules.

- Job1 - Every 5 min from 12:00
- Job2 - Every 5 min from 12:01
- Job3 - Every 5 min from 12:02
- Job4 - Every 5 min from 12:03
- Job5 - Every 5 min from 12:04

The SSIS queries a `Report` table, and if the report hasn't run yet on the given date (check `ReportLog`) and that report is not running currently (check `WorkQueue`) the first (top) report is picked up, and ran.

That query is effectively:

```
SELECT TOP 1 R.ReportID
FROM Report R
LEFT JOIN ReportLog L ON R.ReportID=L.ReportID AND L.RunDate >= CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE())
LEFT JOIN WorkQueue Q ON R.ReportID=Q.ReportID
WHERE R.Active=1
AND L.ReportID IS NULL 
AND Q.ReportID IS NULL
```

The SSIS package, upon selecting this `TOP 1 ReportID` (stored in a SSIS variable), inserts the `ReportID` into `WorkQueue`, so no other instances of the package will try to use that `ReportID`.  The insert happens in the next step after the select.

Most times, most days, this works fine.  However, every so often two SSIS packages end up running at (within a few milliseconds) the exact same time, and both return the same `TOP 1 ReportID` causing issues with one another as they both execute the same procedures, and manipulate the same underlying data.

Right now, we're considering implementing a parent SSIS package which does the `select` and places the `ReportID` into a "buffer" table along with the Job# of one of the 5 child packages to pick up (rather than the child packages all doing their own `select top 1`), but that seems very hacky.

Another option we considered was an `instead of insert` trigger on the `WorkQueue` table which would raise an error on duplicate insertions.

I am wondering if there is any other way within SSIS to prevent this situation without too much redesign.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about avoid the trigger and make use of the OUTPUT clause?

```
INSERT INTO
    WorkQueue
OUTPUT Inserted.ReportID
SELECT TOP 1 R.ReportID
FROM Report R
    LEFT JOIN ReportLog L ON R.ReportID=L.ReportID AND L.RunDate >= CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE())
    LEFT JOIN WorkQueue Q ON R.ReportID=Q.ReportID
WHERE R.Active=1
    AND L.ReportID IS NULL 
    AND Q.ReportID IS NULL;
```

This should allow you to pop row row into the workQueue table to claim it for the current process and simultaneously retrieve the value for SSIS to use.

Comment: I think I just bruised my face with my palm... thank you!

Comment: No worries, plenty of folks haven't discovered the clever tricks you can do with the OUTPUT clause. ;)